# Comment traduire le mot néerlandais « binnenpretje » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, néerlandais

Le mot « binnenpretje » se traduit littéralement par « rigolade intérieure ». C’est une chose marrante dont on se rappelle tout d’un coup. Quand quelqu’un rit de façon imprévue, une autre personne qui l’aperçoit peut soupçonner qu’il rit au nez de lui.
Celui qui rit peut faire disparaître sa méfiance en disant « ce n’était qu’une rigolade intérieure ».

---

Une *rigolade intérieure* n’a rien de sournois. Quelqu’un qui l’éprouve ne raille pas, et il n’essaie pas d’attrister quelqu’un et il ne tente pas de cacher le rire. On rit souvent doucement, mais soudainement, ce qui éveille un peu d’étonnement chez tout le monde qui l’entend. J’ai peut-être laissé penser que le mot s’emploie seulement pour un rire qui interrompt une parole, mais il peut s’agir également d’un rire quand personne ne parle.

Le mot désigne souvent une joie qui surgit quand quelqu’un se souvient d’une bonne facétie qu’il a entendu jadis, ou une chose très marrante qu’il a vécu il y a quelques jours. Cette joie induit quelqu’un à pousser un rire doux.

---

Je me souviens que j’ai trouvé la traduction « amusement en soliloque ». [Cet outil](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amusement%20en%20soliloque&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) que j’utilise volontiers pour voir si des mots ont vraiment cours, n’affiche rien quand j’introduis « amusement en soliloque ». Il semble qu’on n’utilise jamais cette combinaison de mots.

J’espère que vous connaissez des traductions plus brèves et plus usités. Je cherche plutôt un mot argotique qu’un mot soutenu. Je vous donnerai plus de données à propos de « binnenpretje » si vous en avez besoin.

Comment traduire le mot néerlandais « binnenpretje » ?

**Les changements de ce que j’ai écrit**

Tout ce qui se trouve entre les deux lignes est nouveau. J’ai aussi ajusté la partie qui porte sur la phrase « Ce n’était qu’une rigolade intérieure ». J’ai aussi ajouté le lien que j’ai oulié. J’espère que tout devient plus lucide comme ça.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La notion de *rigolade intérieure* renvoie à :

- *Rire en son for intérieur* est la définition littéraire, le *for intérieur* étant "le tribunal de la conscience" (le Robert).
- *Rire sous cape* : rire sans le manifester, souvent entendu dans les contes et histoires enfantines.

S'il s'agit de *rire au nez* d'un interlocuteur d'un incident qui ne le concerne pas :

> Excuses-moi, je *ris au fond de moi* de ce qui est arrivé hier à ... (soutenu)
>
> Excuses-moi *je pouffe* mais cela ne te concerne pas ... (familier voire argotique)

*Pouffer de rire* : "Laisser échapper par saccades des soufflements bruyants, résultat d'un rire qu'on essaie en vain de réprimer". (cnrtl)

---

*Amusement en soliloque* est très soutenu et très rarement utilisé

---

*Complément suite aux précisions de Koenraad*

La seconde définition de *[Wikipédia](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rire_aux_anges)* pour **rire aux anges** semble correspondre à la question :

- Être tellement transporté de joie qu’on paraît comme extasié.
- Rire seul et sans raison connue.
- Se dit particulièrement d’un petit enfant qui rit en dormant.

Rire seul ne doit pas être entendu comme 'rire sans aucune personne autour', mais 'être le seul à rire dans un groupe'.

J'ai souvent entendu *sourire aux anges* lorsqu'il y avait de la douceur, lorsque le *[sou]rire* était l'expression d'un contentement, d'un plaisir innocent, comme ceux suggérés par la troisième définition mais qui peut aussi se retrouver sur certaines sculptures, peintures.
On voit parfois cette expression rayonnante et apaisante sur des visages d'adultes, d'enfants ou de vieillards.

Comment: [En latin, le nom "for" signifiait "marché" dans le sens de "juridiction".](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/45/en-son-for-interieur/)

Comment: @ChrisW le Robert : 1235 ; "loi, coutume" en ancien gascon ; du latin *forum* "place publique", "tribunal"

Comment: Oui, dont "foire". Si je ne me trompe pas, "for" n'est pas un mot français moderne. Je l'ai trouvé dans le dictionnaire, mais seulement associé à la phrase, "Dans mon for intérieur".

Comment: *Rire sous cape* implique plutôt qu'on se moque mentalement de quelqu'un (généralement parce qu'on se montre plus malin que cette personne), pas qu'on a une soudaine pensée rigolote.

Comment: J’ai suivi le lien que vous m’avez donné. J’y ai vu qu’on a mis « binnenpretjes hebben » sur la page comme traduction flamande de « rire sous cape », mais je ne pense pas que ces choses soulignent la même notion, comme @Circeus l’a dit. D’ailleurs, je vous remercie pour les phrases que vous m’avez données.

Comment: Il me semble que « sourire aux anges » frappe presque la cible. Voici la seule facette qui se frotte à « binnenpretje » : Je pense qu'elle a quelque chose à voir avec un événement heureux dont on se souvient, plutôt qu’avec une chose marrante qui revient à l’esprit. Je suis désolé que je suis si pointilleux, mais selon moi, c’est un sous-entendu qui doit être pris en compte.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin Pour améliorer votre français déjà très au point : "Je suis désolé d'être si pointilleux .."  - Votre commentaire définit exactement le *sourire aux anges* : un événnement heureux, qui peut être drôle, amusant, bienfaisant, mais qui n'a rien à voir avec l'ironie, le sarcasme, l'humour décapant.

Answer (score 3):

Un éclat de rire soudain et incontrollé, peu importe sa cause, est une *crise de fou rire*. 
C'est un terme employé surtout si ce rire est particulièrement malvenu (notamment à la télé, sur un plateau de tournage ou une scène de théâtre, à l'église...).

Les termes de cl-r impliquent précisément qu'**on ne rit pas visiblement**.

Comment: Merci ! Vôtre traduction se rapproche assez bien de « rigolade intérieure », si j’ai bien compris vôtre réponse, mais n’est pas encore entièrement satisfaisante. Quand j’aurai plus de temps, j’étendrai les renseignements pour que l’idée de « rigolade intérieure » ressortisse mieux.

Comment: @Circeus J'ai mentionné *rire sous cape* pour éclairer la première 'traduction' de Koenradd ; en effet, c'est un rire dissimulé. Je n'ai trouvé que *pouffer de rire* comme traduction argotique souhaitée dans la question, la définition jointe contredit ce que vous avez grasseyé. La *crise de four rire*, naît souvent de la tension nerveuse de l'environnement dans lequel on se trouve, ce n'est pas un rire déconnecté de la situation ambiante.

Comment: La crise de fou rire implique d'abord quelque de bruyant et visible, ce n'est pas ce que recherche le PO.